# Elasticsearch 5.6 combining constant score and bool queries

Tags: php, elasticsearch, search-engine, relevance, booleanquery

I'm currently working on a **search engine** for a website which is using a **PHP API** querying into an **Elasticsearch 5.6** index.
I have been stuck for a long while on a specific query and that's why I am looking for some help from the community.
Let me give some more details:

- The ES index contains documents which are persons and those persons have a birthname and a lastname (both values are identicals if the person is a man or a woman, who isn't married). There also a few more pieces of information like a firstname, a date and others not relevant to my question.
- The website search engine only has one field for the birthname and the lastname.

I have been asked to create a query so whenever a user enters a value in that field I must get the following results:

- If the value match 100% the birthname OR the lastname of a person I should get them with exactly the same score value
- If the value doesn't match 100% then I'll get the results with at least 5 characters that follow similar in their birthname OR lastname
- The results have to be sorted in a very specific way.
  First, the results which match 100% sorted by date, alphabetical order on birthname and lastname then the results which match partially sorted by score, date and alphabetical order.

The fields i'm querying are respectively named **nom.unsplit**, **nom.ngram**, **nomNaissance.unsplit**, **nomNaissance.ngram**

I have been trying this query which is giving perfect results for a search on the birthname but is failing to find the lastname (obviously). And if I add the 2 other fields to the query the results are still not satisfying because elasticsearch is giving a better relevance score if the lastname match than if the birthname match.

[ES query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIdlq.png)

I have also tried constant_score queries with a filter and a boost. It's working but only if I'm looking for the 100% result.
I have tried combining bool query and constant score query but I can't get it to work.
I'd like to add that the search engine contains more fields so I need to be able to insert this specific query in a bigger bool query which gathers all the subqueries I'm already using.
I'll take any advice and I'll give complementary pieces of information if needed.

Comment: If you search for e.g. `birthname:X OR lastname:X` would the score be double if both the birthname and lastname are X than if one one of the two was?

Comment: no the score must be the same as if only one of the fields was X

Comment: I was asking how elasticsearch is currently scoring. I thought the default lucene scoring took the maximum score on each field to determine the score of a document, however I may be wrong.